# Как подключить Android и Windows девайсы в одну виртуальную локальную сеть?

Tags: android, windows, сеть, vpn

Для LAN-игр нужно подключить телефон на Android и ноутбук на Windows 10 в одну виртуальную локальную сеть. Устройства находятся не в одной локальной сети, но имеют доступ в интернет. Есть ли способ подключить их вместе с помощью p2p? Для двух компьютеров решений довольно много, (тот же Hamachi и Tunggle) но для Android-Windows не нашел.

Приложение LogMeIn для Android - это не p2p а очередной TeamViewer, так что, пожалуйста, не предлагайте его...

Comment: https://www.tinc-vpn.org/platforms/ ?